# Can one send one payment to two private keys through 1 QR code?

Tags: payment, payment-processors

Is it possible to send via one QR code or bitcoin address one payment that can be divided or split by a percentage of my choice to two private key QR codes, individual users, a percentage of the amount deposited on one QR conventionally by only havin to scan one QR. 
What I'm looking for is a platform where one QR code allows me as a shopkeeper to price my items and have them sold so as the payments go or are otherwised forwarded for no fee direct to the suppliers as well as myself in one function. So that I don't have to "do the books" at the end of each month, rather,  price my items with one QR code per item and receive the profit as a percentage split or assinged number, wholsale price, of our choice so as to be paid instantly along side the wholesaler plus as many other parties without any interference of our own...
Any ideas one how I can do this or programmers who could do such a thing and are willing to help?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do some post processing.
A QR code can encode only one address.
But once you receive the funds you can split them up however you want between however many addresses you want (this would mean another transaction of course).
You could do this manually if your volume is low, or automate it via a script that talks to the receiving wallet.